# Undo or lock file in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

If a user has locked a file in TFS 2013 in their workspace and I need to unlock it (as Administrator), is it really just `tf lock /:none {filename}`, or is it `tf undo [/workspace:workspacename[;workspaceowner]] {filename}`? I'm aware of Sidekicks, just concerned about command line.

Comment: I would suggest you install [Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/), makes it much easier to do things like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first command "tf lock /:none" will remove the lock only. The second "tf undo" will undo the check-out completely.

The first has no effect on the local workspace and is really a server operation. The later has a direct effect on their local workspace.

I would suggest you use the "lock" command only unless a user has left your organisation.